# Akka Graph with throttling messages

Tags: scala, akka, throttling

I try consider throttle messages using akka streams.

As for me, the simpliest  idea for that is to read stream lines from file handle it and give to the target service.

So next code covers idea (`source ~> lines ~> sink`):

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Restart
import akka.actor.{
  Actor,
  ActorLogging,
  ActorRef,
  ActorSystem,
  OneForOneStrategy,
  Props,
  SupervisorStrategy
}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{
  FileIO,
  Flow,
  Framing,
  GraphDSL,
  RunnableGraph,
  Sink
}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ClosedShape, ThrottleMode}
import akka.util.ByteString

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.language.postfixOps

class StreamSenderActorV1(target: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case StreamBookV1(filename) =>
      val materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(context) // Materializing and running a stream always requires a Materializer to be in implicit scope.
      val sink: Sink[Any, NotUsed] = Sink.actorRef(target, NotUsed)

      import java.nio.file.Paths
      val source = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(filename))

      val lines: Flow[ByteString, StreamLineV1, NotUsed] = Framing
        .delimiter(
          ByteString(System.lineSeparator),
          10000,
          allowTruncation = true
        )
        .map(bs => bs.utf8String)
        .map(StreamLineV1)

      lines
        .throttle(1, Duration(2, "seconds"), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping) // throttle - to slow down the stream to 1 element per second.
        .to(sink)

      RunnableGraph
        .fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
          implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
            import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._
            source ~> lines ~> sink
            ClosedShape
        })
        .run()(materializer)
  }

  override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(10, Duration(60, "seconds")) {
      case _: Exception => Restart
    }
}
class StreamReceiverActorV1 extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case StreamLineV1(line) => log.info(s"line: $line")
    case x                  => log info s"all: $x"
  }
}

case class StreamBookV1(fileName: String)
case class StreamLineV1(line: String)

object StreamSenderActorV1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("Thottler-Messages")
    val target = system.actorOf(Props[StreamReceiverActorV1], "receiver")
    val sender =
      system.actorOf(Props(classOf[StreamSenderActor], target), "sender")

    sender ! StreamBookV1("throttle-streams/src/main/resources/log.txt")

    Thread sleep 4000
    system terminate
  }
}
```

unfortunately result is different to expectations (delay is absent):

```
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.414] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 1.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.415] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 2.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.415] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 3.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.415] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 4.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.415] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 5.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.415] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 6.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.415] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 7.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.416] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 8.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.416] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 9.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.416] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 10.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.416] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: 11.
[INFO] [09/23/2019 14:11:22.416] [Thottler-Messages-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Thottler-Messages/user/receiver] all: NotUsed
```

### Question is

How to use `throttle` in `Graph` stream flow?

### P.S.

I've tried to apply `throttle` with `source` directly result is the same.

### P.S.2.

[Example of throttling simplier streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html#example) provided by akka works for me correctly.

Possible `throttle` can be useless in my case because of applying it for `Flow` that already has specified integration rule for the Graph (`~> lines ~> sink`).
...I have no ideas how to fix if for Graph.

### Environment:

- `scala 2.13.0`
- `sbt 1.3.0`
- `akka 2.5.25`

Answer (score 2):

I think the root cause here is that `throttle` is "applied" to `lines` as a mutator - which is not how it works :) Basically all these operators on streams (`map`, `filter`, `throttle`, `via`, `mapConcat`, etc.) only create an *immutable* blueprint of the computation. So, roughly speaking, every operation create a different "copy" of the blueprint, but never modifies the original one.

So, in your case

```
lines
   .throttle(1, Duration(2, "seconds"), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
   .to(sink)
```

returns a new throttled "blueprint" - and then immediately discarded.

So, the way to fix it is simple - use what the `throttled` returned. One option is:

```
val lines = ... // same as now
val throttledLines = lines.throttled(...)

RunnableGraph
        .fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
          implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
            import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._
            source ~> throttledLines ~> sink
            ClosedShape
        })
        .run()(materializer)
```

However, since your graph is "linear" you might want to use a more elegant "fluent" interface:

```
val source = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(filename))
val lines = ... // same as now

val runnableStream = source.via(lines).throttle(...).to(sink)
runnableStream.run()(materializer)
```

Comment: I've tried to use your idea... but I have not detected any `throttled` method in API, my IDE has no suggestions and as result I can't resolve compilation error for that...

Comment: Am I correctly understood? You want me to use `val throttledLines = lines.throttle(1, Duration(2, "seconds"), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)`. Which type will be `throttledLines`? ... i get compilation error without specifying type because of `~>` unresolved after proposed modifications.

Comment: Can you post a compilation error you're getting? `throttledLines` should be exactly the same time as `lines` - `Flow[ByteString, StreamLineV1, NotUsed]`. Note that there's no `to` in my example. `lines.throttle(...).to` would be of type `Sink[...]`

Comment: `Sink[ByteString, NotUsed]` type was required. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to have throttling result as `Flow[ByteString, StreamLineV1, NotUsed]`? How?

Comment: @Sergii As I've said, `lines.throttle(...)` should already be a `Flow[...]`, unless you attach it to `source` first. To disambiguate: `lines.throttle(...)` is a `Flow[...]`, but `source.via(lines).throttle` or `source ~> lines.throttle` is a `Source`

Comment: I was unsuccessful with converting `throttle` result to `Flow[...]` because of different type that leads compilation error and this is main reason why I asked help. Playing with your ideas I've constructed `Sink[...]` and I voted up your answer. ...but `Flow[..]` result is not resolved part yet, sorry.

Comment: @Sergii now that's really interesting :) Could you share your updated code? I'm probably doing something differently, but when I use `throttle` it gives me a Flow. I actually have a piece of code that clearly shows that throttle produces a flow, not a `Sink` or a `Source`, but it's in a private repo, so I can't share a link

Comment: @JOHN next link contains `Sink` [result](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/hello_scala/blob/master/throttle-stream-graph/src/main/scala/runnable_graph/StreamSenderActor.scala). I would like also to have a chance meet your solution with `Flow` result after throttling. I'd like to have `val throttledLines: Flow[...] = lines.throttled(...)` but it is not :(